# How are the segment registers initialized for x86 (80286) in protected mode?

Tags: x86, operating-system, protected-mode

I'm taking an operating systems class, and I'm a little unsure about segment registers. I've checked a couple of places online, but I haven't gotten a clear-cut answer to my question (even my professor gave a roundabout spiel, alluding to a later lecture).

How are the segment registers, like `CS` (code segment) or `DS` (data segment), initialized? Do they change based on different processes (i.e., are they saved-restored during a context switch)? Or are they initialized by the bootloader/kernel and left static for all processes to use?

Comment: It depends to some extent on the OS.  What OS do you want to know about?  And are you really asking about the 80286 specifically - it had a 16-bit protected mode that AFAIK was only ever really used by OS/2, Windows 3.0, and some DOS extenders, and was obsoleted when the 32-bit 80386 came along.  If so then maybe Retrocomputing.SE is the better site.

Comment: In general, on the 286, different processes would need to use different segments - that was the only way to keep their memory spaces separate.  They could use different selectors in the GDT, or the same selectors in different LDTs.  In either case, the segment registers would need to be reloaded on context switches for the changes to take effect.  But again, is it really the 286 you are asking about?  That is 1980s-era ancient history and is a strange topic for an OS class in the year 2021.

Comment: @NateEldredge: IIRC, doesn't 386 Protected Mode just extend 286 Protected Mode with 32-bit?  That's why addresses in GDT / LDT entries are broken up into such awkward pieces in multiple fields.  (Related: [Which "very esoteric processor instructions" are used by OS/2?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21734) mentions that OS/2 was the only major OS to be developed in the time between 286 and 386 that didn't care about portability to non-x86, so it actually used segmentation and ring 1 / ring 2 extensively, while later OSes just used paging.

Comment: Anyway, I assume in https://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table that the pieces of base and limit above 16-bit were just crammed into parts that 286 left reserved for future use, while keeping their low16 in the 286-compatible places, so 286 OSes would run on 386 using that GDT format, I guess leaving `base[31:24]` holding garbage or zero.  Instead of rearranging to make the 32-bit base be contiguous :/

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, of course, the segmentation mechanism didn't really change between 286 and 386.  And maybe the technical answer to OP's question doesn't change much either: if segmentation is able to be used at all, then LDTR and segment registers have to be reloaded on context switch.   But the practical implications are pretty different.